# Are solutions to polynomial equations subideals in a polynomial ring?

Tags: polynomials, ideals, polynomial-rings

I'm wondering how can i make sense of a partial solution to a  two-system of polynomial equations.
Let $\{f,g\}\subseteq K[x,y]$ be polynomials in a polynomial ring over the field $K$. Given the equations:
$$f(x,y)=a$$
$$g(x,y)=b$$
Every solution is contained in the affine variety $\mathcal{V}(I_0)≠\emptyset$ of the ideal
$$I_0=\langle f(x,y)-a,g(x,y)-b\rangle$$
Suppose i have a function $t\in K[x,y]$ such that:
$$I_1=\langle f(t,y)-a,g(t,y)-b\rangle=$$
$$\langle a-a,g(t,y)-b\rangle=\langle g(t,y)-b\rangle$$
Is there a relationship between $I_0$ and $I_1$?

---

Given these conditions, i thought about the possibility of the ideals satisfying: $I_1\subseteq I_0$, as in the following example: let
$$I_0=\langle x+y-a,xy-b\rangle$$
And let $t=a-y$, then
$$I_1=\langle ay-y^2-b\rangle$$
We can show that $I_1\subseteq I_0$ by showing that $r\in I_0$ satisfies:
$$r=-y(x+y-a)+xy-b=$$
$$ay-y^2-b$$
So
$$I_1=\langle r\rangle\subseteq I_0$$
But is this generally the case? How can i prove it? Maybe the ideals satisfy some other relation (i.e not inclussion)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found something interesting... We can extend the polynomial ideal $I_0\subseteq K[x,y]$ to the field of algebraic functions with degree one (in two variables) by noting:
$$I_0\subseteq A[x,y]=\left\{x\in K[x,y]^2|x=\frac{n(x,y)}{d(x,y)};n\in K[x,y],d\in K[x,y]/\{0\}\right\}$$
By performing this extension, we can define a function $\eta\in A[x,y]$ as the solution to the equation:
$$\eta(f(x,y)-a)+g(x,y)-b=g(t,y)-b$$
Which then shows:
$$\eta=\frac{g(t,y)-g(x,y)}{f(x,y)-a}$$
(remember, $t\in K[x,y]$) this is utterly unexpected for me, because this shows that the ideal inclussion $I_1\subseteq I_0$ depends explicitly in the base set of the ideals, and we have the implication statement:
$$I_0\subseteq A[x,y]\Rightarrow I_1\subseteq I_0$$
But the same statement for ideals in the ring $K[x,y]$ might not be true (i.e when $\eta\notin K[x,y]$)